# Is there a way to automatically and programmatically download the latest IP ranges used by Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure

Microsoft has provided a URL where you can download the public IP ranges used by Microsoft Azure.

> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=41653

The question is, is there a way to download the XML file from that site automatically using Python or other scripts?  I am trying to schedule a task to grab the new IP range file and process it for my firewall policies.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes! There is!

#### But of course you need to do a bit more work than expected to achieve this.

I discovered this question when I realized Microsoft’s page only works via JavaScript when loaded in a browser. Which makes automation via Curl practically unusable; I’m not manually downloading this file when updates happen. Instead IO came up with this Bash “one-liner” that works well for me.

First, let’s define that base URL like this:

```
MICROSOFT_IP_RANGES_URL="https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=41653"
```

Now just run this Curl command—that parses the returned web page HTML with a few chained Greps—like this:

```
curl -Lfs "${MICROSOFT_IP_RANGES_URL}" | grep -Eoi '<a [^>]+>' | grep -Eo 'href="[^\"]+"' | grep "download.microsoft.com/download/" | grep -m 1 -Eo '(http|https)://[^"]+'
```

The returned output is a nice and clean final URL like this:

```
https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/1/8/018E208D-54F8-44CD-AA26-CD7BC9524A8C/PublicIPs_20181224.xml
```

Which is *exactly* what one needs to automatic the direct download of that XML file. If you need to then assign that value to a URL just wrap it in `$()` like this:

```
MICROSOFT_IP_RANGES_URL_FINAL=$(curl -Lfs "${MICROSOFT_IP_RANGES_URL}" | grep -Eoi '<a [^>]+>' | grep -Eo 'href="[^\"]+"' | grep "download.microsoft.com/download/" | grep -m 1 -Eo '(http|https)://[^"]+')
```

And just access that URL via `$MICROSOFT_IP_RANGES_URL_FINAL` and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use `wget` writing in a text editor and saving it as `scriptNameYouWant.sh` will give you a bash script that will download the xml file you want.

```
#! /bin/bash
wget http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/1/8/018E208D-54F8-44CD-AA26-CD7BC9524A8C/PublicIPs_21050223.xml
```

Of course, you can run the command directly from a terminal and have the exact result.

If you want to use Python, one way is:

Again, write in a text editor and save as `scriptNameYouWant.py` the folllowing:

```
import urllib2
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/1/8/018E208D-54F8-44CD-AA26-CD7BC9524A8C/PublicIPs_21050223.xml").read()
f = open("xmlNameYouWant.xml", "w")
f.write(str(page))
f.close()
```

I'm not that good with python or bash though, so I guess there is a more elegant way in both python or bash.

EDIT

You get the xml despite the dynamic url using `curl`. What worked for me is this:

```
#! /bin/bash
FIRSTLONGPART="http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/1/8/018E208D-54F8-44CD-AA26-CD7BC9524A8C/PublicIPs_"
INITIALURL="http://www.microsoft.com/EN-US/DOWNLOAD/confirmation.aspx?id=41653"
OUT="$(curl -s $INITIALURL | grep -o -P '(?<='$FIRSTLONGPART').*(?=.xml")'|tail -1)"
wget -nv $FIRSTLONGPART$OUT".xml"
```

Again, I'm sure that there is a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: The problem I have is that the link is dynamic (probably sign url which is dynamically changed).  It will change every Wednesday and there is a good chance that the "new" link is created.

Comment: @nicklee The script under the EDIT addresses the dynamically changing url

Comment: Addressing the dynamic link, you can perform a web request to the link provided by @nicklee and search the HTML by splitting it into an array by quotes, filtering for elements starting with `https://download.microsoft.com`
 and containing `ServiceTags`, then selecting the first element. This element will most likely be the direct download link you're looking for. I can write a small script if it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an one-liner to get the URL of the JSON file:

```
$ curl -sS https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56519 | egrep -o 'https://download.*?\.json' | uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

I enhanced the last response a bit and I'm able to download the JSON file:

```
#! /bin/bash

download_link=$(curl -sS https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56519 | egrep -o 'https://download.*?\.json' | uniq | grep -v refresh)

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  wget $download_link ; echo "Latest file downloaded"
else 
  echo "Download failed"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight mod to ushuz script from 2020 - as that was producing 2 different entries and unique doesn't work for me in Windows -

$list=@(curl -sS https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56519 | egrep -o 'https://download.*?.json')
$list.Get(2)

That outputs the valid path to the json, which you can punch into another variable for use for grepping or whatever.