# Download Azure IP list and extract values for specific service name

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to download the list of Azure IPs which can be found here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519 . The issue is it returns a bunch of HTML instead of the json file with the values I need. I'm not sure how to have powershell perform the download and store the json content in a variable I can filter through to pull the IP ranges I need. This would need to run in an azure function app and would not be on a PC or VM.

I've tried this recommendation but no luck. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66179741/4396701

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar Problem. I wrote a Script which grabs the latest version of the file and saves each category of IPs in a seperate File.
https://github.com/noah1400/AzureIPRangeFetcher
You probably need to adjust the script to your needs.

```
$url = 'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56519'
$pageContent = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url
if ($pageContent.Content -match 'data-bi-id="downloadretry" href="(?<url>.*\.json?)"') { 
    $jsonUrl = $matches['url'] 
}
$jsonContent = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $jsonUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this URL,
https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/1/D/71D86715-5596-4529-9B13-DA13A5DE5B63/ServiceTags_Public_20230508.json

When I visited this page, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519,
I found the actual download url by clicking on the save button when prompted to save by the browser, and then checking the URL in the browser download history.

One thing to notice is that it has a date associated with it, so it'll be better to fetch IPs using service tags and some other azure API.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: that link did end up working for me and I was able to get what I needed. Still not exactly sure how you found it. Do you know how that could be done with powershell so this whole thing can be automated?

Comment: found this link in browser download history

Comment: The URL is updated once per week. As show by the date, it was retrieved in may 2023. The current URL (as of this writing) is https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/1/D/71D86715-5596-4529-9B13-DA13A5DE5B63/ServiceTags_Public_20240212.json . However the only way to get the most recent URL appears to be parsing the HTML on https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56519.

Answer (score 0):

In 2021, it looks like Microsoft *quietly* released the [Service Tag Discovery API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/general-availability-for-service-tag-discovery-api/) to be able to programmatically retrieve Azure Service Tags & IPs. You can use REST, PowerShell, or Azure CLI to retrieve the JSON.

Documentation: [Use the Service Tag Discovery API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/service-tags-overview#use-the-service-tag-discovery-api)

REST:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Network/locations/{location}/serviceTags?api-version=2023-09-01
```

PS:

```
$serviceTags = Get-AzNetworkServiceTag -Location eastus2
$storage = $serviceTags.Values | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Storage" }
$storage.Properties.AddressPrefixes
```

CLI:

```
az network list-usages --location eastus -o table
```

***HOWEVER***, there is a catch.

> NOTE: It takes up to 4 weeks for new Service Tag data to propagate in the API results across all Azure regions. Because of this process, your API data results may be out of sync with the downloadable JSON file as the API data represents a subset of the tags currently in the downloadable JSON file.